# How to cancel a asyncTask when a swipe tab is rotated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Well, i have 3 swipe tabs and in each tab i have called a asynctask in the fragments onCreateView() method. Its showing result in normal case but the problem is when i rotate the screen. Basically it closes forcefully when a asynctask is going on and before completing the task-i rotate the screen.

So, i have tried to cancel the asynctask in onPause and call it again in onCreateView(). Below is the code inside a fragment:

```
public class AllFragment extends Fragment 
{
  SearchBusBeans searchBusObj;
  ArrayList<SearchBusBeans> searchBusObj_arr;

SearchingBusesAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ .....
  ....
 searchBusObj_arr = new ArrayList<SearchBusBeans>();
  new GetSearchedBusesAsync().execute();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    GetSearchedBusesAsync asyncObj = new GetSearchedBusesAsync();
    if(asyncObj.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        asyncObj.cancel(true);
    }
}



private class GetSearchedBusesAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
 {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { super.onPreExecute(); }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        if(isCancelled())
            this.cancel(true);

        if(!isCancelled())
        {...........
           ......do my codes.......
           searchBusObj = new SearchBusBeans();
           searchBusObj.setname(j_name);
           searchBusObj_arr.add(searchBusObj);  
          }
     return null;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        myAdapter = new SearchingBusesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), searchBusObj_arr);
        gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
  } //end of asynctask
 } //end of fragment
```

Now as you can see that i have cancelled the asynctask in onPause. and inside doInBackground() i have done my code in condition-if(!isCancelled()). So, shouldn't the asynctask exit and not go to onPostExecute()?

Where am i going wrong? and how to do the cancellation and execution properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your fragment to retain its state through a rotation. This will allow your `AsyncTask` to keep running.

```
public class AllFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

Override the `onCreate` method of the fragment and call `setRetainInstance(true);`. This keeps the fragment alive so that it doesn't get destroyed and then recreated during a configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to stop the execution of an AsyncTask (on any event,not necessary on rotation):

**1)** Save your AsyncTask in a variable when you call `.execute()`

```
mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

**2)** Then, when you need to stop the task call `.cancel()`

```
if(mTask != null) {
    mTask.cancel(true);
}
```

This approach works for me perfectly and it is usable almost for any scenario. Hope it helps!